# Expo v43 React Native Getstream Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: react-native, expo, getstream-io

I'm using GetStream activity feeds in my react native application. All was working well in expo sdk v40, but when upgrading to v41 (and subsequently 42 and 43) I suddenly receive a Maximum call stack size exceeded error:

```js
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

This error is located at:
    in FeedInner (at Feed.js:1236)
    in StreamAppConsumer (at Feed.js:1240)
    in Feed (at FlatFeed.js:27)
    in FlatFeed (at Feed.js:229)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Feed.js:227)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Feed.js:96)
    in StreamApp (at Feed.js:95)
    in FeedScreen (created by Connect(FeedScreen))
```

I've worked through my screens to ensure that there is not a setState/render issue (i.e. the screen renders exactly once). I've also noticed this doesn't occur if I change the feedgroup to 'notification' rather than 'timeline'.

```js
<FlatFeed 
  styles={{ container: { paddingTop: 40 }} }
  feedGroup='timeline'
  options={{
    limit: 1,
    refresh: false
  }}
  noPagination={true}
  Activity={(props) => (
    props && <FeedItem 
      {...props}
      navigate={navigate}
      />
  )}
  flatListProps={{
    ListEmptyComponent: 
      <View style={{flex: 1, borderWidth: 0, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center', padding: 20}}>
        <View style={{width: '50%', aspectRatio: 1, borderWidth: 0, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <ImageBackground
              style={{flex: 1}}
              source={require('../assets/images/Share_onboarding_image.png')}
              resizeMode="contain"
            />
          </View>    
          <View style={{flex: 0, padding: 10, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text>blah</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
    }} 
/>
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.8",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "4.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "7.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^3.2.13",
    "aws-amplify": "^2.3.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.5",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-activity-feed": "^1.1.1",
    "expo-application": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-contacts": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-device": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~12.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^11.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-modules-core": "~0.6.4",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.5",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "filter-obj": "^2.0.1",
    "isobject": "^4.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.22",
    "query-string": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-bundle-visualizer": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-cross-actionsheet": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-swipe-cards": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-swipe-cards-deck": "^0.2.20",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-hooks": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sentry-expo": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "9.0.2",
    "jest-expo": "^44.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0",
    "visualize-bundle": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  }
}
```

I've tried a lot of things here and sometimes can get the screen to load but when i click to another screen first and then across it crashes. The json payload doesn't appear to be too large but I'm stuck. Any help most appreciated!

Comment: It is likely that somewhere your code is calling itself recursively. With your upgrades, did you also upgrade react-navigation - I have previously experienced this issue when the navigator is calling itself during a listen event.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've checked for recursion and don't believe it exists anywhere (of course I could be wrong and haven't found it yet). I do suspect react navigation might be an issue as I'm still on v4